# R: How to make column of predictions for logistic regression model?

Tags: r, predict

So I have a data set called `x`. The contents are simple enough to just write out so I'll just outline it here:

- the dependent variable, `Report`, in the first column is binary yes/no (0 = no, 1 = yes)
- the subsequent 3 columns are all categorical variables (`race.f`, `sex.f`, `gender.f`) that have all been converted to factors, and they're designated by numbers (e.g. 1= white, 2 = black, etc.)

I have run a logistic regression on x as follows:

```
glm <- glm(Report ~ race.f + sex.f + gender.f, data=x,
           family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

And I can check the fitted probabilities by looking at `summary(glm$fitted)`.

My question: How do I create a fifth column on the right side of this data set `x` that will include the predictions (i.e. fitted probabilities) for `Report`? Of course, I could just insert the `glm$fitted` as a column, but I'd like to try to write a code that predicts it based on whatever is in the race, sex, gender columns for a more generalized use.

Right now I the follow code which I will hope create a predicted column as well as lower and upper bounds for the confidence interval.

```
xnew <- cbind(xnew, predict(glm5, newdata = xnew, type = "link", se = TRUE))
xnew <- within(xnew, {
  PredictedProb <- plogis(fit)
  LL <- plogis(fit - (1.96 * se.fit))
  UL <- plogis(fit + (1.96 * se.fit))
})
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'race.f' not found
```

after the `cbind` code.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a few typo in your codes; First Xnew calls on glm5 but your model as far as I can see is glm (by the way using glm as name of your output is probably not a good idea). Secondly make sure the variable race.f is actually in the dataset you wish to do the prediction from. My guess is R can't find that variable hence the error.